# Integrating SharePoint with a web application

Tags: sharepoint

Is it possible to have a Java/J2EE web application integrate/communicate with SharePoint to load, search, and retrieve docs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can communicate with SharePoint from Java using the web services:
http://www.developer.com/tech/article.php/3104621

- Uploading files to WSS:
  [Upload file to SharePoint WSS 3.0 with WebRequest PUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061826/upload-file-to-sharepoint-wss-3-0-with-webrequest-put)
- Searching docs: /_vti_bin/Search.asmx
- Lists (can query a particular library): /vti_bin/Lists.asmx

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint exposes a lot of its functionality through web services.  If you are familiar with working with web services, this could be the easiest way for you to work with Sharepoint.  I found this site just now http://www.developer.com/tech/article.php/3104621  which shows some of the break down of web services available although the code is in VB.  If you do additional searches on Sharepoint and Web Services, you should get more sites that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, web services are the way to go.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479390.aspx

I've done some work on this, with Java, and it's pretty easy to get them talking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use web services as others have suggested to integrate at the service level, this might be the best way.

There is however, the possibility to intergrate at the UI level using Web Service Remote Portlets. There is a WSRP Toolkit for Sharepoint:

http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2008/12/05/announcing-the-wsrp-toolkit-for-sharepoint.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You can use the CNS Media GateWay which can help to intergrate sharepoint or any other ms server with your java web application.

You can connect from any custom application like java to MS Exchange (2000 - 2013), MS SharePoint, Dynamics CRM, Dynamics NAV and many more via the CNS ODBC and JDBC driver, thus accessing, for example, the entire Exchange mailbox from your custom application.

Please let me know if you need some more information.

for more info visit:

http://www.connecting-software.com

Comment: You may want to reformulate your answer to sound less like a sales pitch, and also disclose your own affiliation with the product and/or site.